# Sharepoint Workflow - Conditional Redirect

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have created a workflow that allows for staff to fill in an empty field in a list item through a Workflow initiation form.

There's a good chance that multiple staff may try and enter information in the same list item at the same time, so I'd like to use my workflow to try and catch that, so people aren't overwriting each other.  However, I'm not sure how to do the last portion....

If field is blank, do the workflow and continue to the SourceURL (a thank you page); [got it]

Else (if field isn't blank), advise that this item has already been filled out, and to choose another.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint automatically does concurrency checking and will prevent someone from updating a list item if it has since been updated by someone else.  This has nothing to do with workflows.